# Looking for an android code that toggles "Enhanced 4G LTE Mode" by just opening a app

Tags: android, lte, 4g

My device, the Lenovo Vibe K5 (A6020), has a bug where toggling cellular data on or off messes with VoLTE capabilities and disables it, with the only way to fix it being disabling and re-enabling "Enhanced 4G LTE Mode" from the mobile network's settings. I was wondering how I should make a app that can do this for me.
I am new to android and wanted to solve this error of my phone through a app.
I read about TelephonyManager and ConnectivityManage but not able to do what i want..
somebody help me here!!

Comment: I don't know if it can be done via program. But I have a similar problem in which I need to forcefully use 4G and here's what I do - Open phone dialer and type **`*#*#4636#*#*`** which opens testing screen, and from phone information preferred network type can be used. Since I am lazy, I made an app for it - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?hl=en&id=com.nabin.lrrh

Comment: so How can i toggle lte with whatever ...  you shared..??

Comment: see I want to develop a app which can check if 4g lte is enabled ..if so it disable it and again enable it . then i want to use handlers with runnable to repeat the same after every 10 mins...